# How to alter and animate a div the right way?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a div like this:

```
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2"></div>
    <div class="class3"></div>
    <div class="class4">
         <div class="class5"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This div exists several times on the page.

Now i want to remove some of the child elements, rearrange others and animate that process the right way.

Currently i do it like this.

Example:

```
var mainElement = $('class1');

mainElement.find('class2').css('property','value');
mainElement.find('class3').remove();
mainElement.find('class4').animate({'property': 'value'});
```

This works but it is not as smooth as i would like it to be. When doing it to one element at a time it works but even that is a bit choppy. However, the main problem is that this code is execute on page load and like i said before, it is applied to more then on element at the same time. Then it gets really choppy, to a point where you don't see the animation at all.

Could someone explain to me how to do it the right way?

When i do, for example $('class1').fadOut() that works pretty smooth, even for 50 elements at the same time.

Greetings,
Andy

Comment: And what is it that you'd like to do, exactly? Precise answers depend on specific questions (though they can be extrapolated to more generic solutions).

Comment: I want the transformation from the old div to the new altered one animated as smooth as .fadeOut(). I'm not sure how i should explain it better, sound pretty clear to me. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what you're animating, but if you're moving divs in such a way as to cause a page re-flow, you will get poor performance. Try taking your divs out of the page flow by making them absolutely positioned. The fade would perform well as it doesn't affect layout.

Comment: I'm talking about the reddit.com startpage. Each post is the div (class1) i'm talking about. I try, for example to animate the title font size from each post. Try: $('div.thing.link').fadeOut('1000') on reddit.com